# Custom user control cannot be found in the solution?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a simple Sudoku application, where each 3x3 squares is a user control, with this skeleton code in `CellBlock.Designer.cs` and nothing but the automatically generated code in `CellBlock.cs`:

```
namespace Sudoku
{
    partial class CellBlock
    {

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.CellOne = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.CellFour = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.CellFive = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.CellSix = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.CellTwo = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.CellThree = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.CellSeven = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.CellEight = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.CellNine = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // CellOne
            // 
            this.CellOne.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.CellOne.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.CellOne.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 8);
            this.CellOne.Mask = "0";
            this.CellOne.Name = "CellOne";
            this.CellOne.PromptChar = ' ';
            this.CellOne.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(26, 26);
            this.CellOne.TabIndex = 0;
            this.CellOne.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            //CellTwo through CellNine omitted for brevity

        // 
        // CellBlock
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellNine);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellEight);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellSeven);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellThree);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellTwo);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellSix);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellFive);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellFour);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CellOne);
        this.Name = "CellBlock";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 107);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellOne;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellFour;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellFive;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellSix;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellTwo;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellThree;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellSeven;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellEight;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox CellNine;
}
```

}

These files are in the same solution as `Sudoku.cs`, the main file. I simply added a user control to the solution through the project menu. This is the code in `Sudoku.Designer.cs`, once again, automatically generated by Visual Studio.

```
namespace Sudoku
{
    partial class Sudoku
    {

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Sudoku));
            this.cellBlock1 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();
            this.cellBlock2 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();
            this.cellBlock3 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();
            this.cellBlock4 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();
            this.cellBlock5 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();
            this.cellBlock6 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();
            this.cellBlock7 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();
            this.cellBlock8 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();
            this.cellBlock9 = new Sudoku.CellBlock(); //errors occur at these lines

}


        private CellBlock cellBlock1;
        private CellBlock cellBlock2;
        private CellBlock cellBlock3;
        private CellBlock cellBlock4;
        private CellBlock cellBlock5;
        private CellBlock cellBlock6;
        private CellBlock cellBlock7;
        private CellBlock cellBlock8;
        private CellBlock cellBlock9;

    }
}
```

I think that's all correct, even though I'm omitting some of the automatically-generated code for the sake of brevity. When I build the solution, I get 9 errors like this:
    The type name 'CellBlock' does not exist in the type 'Sudoku.Sudoku'

referencing the lines that read: `this.cellBlock1 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();`, etc. I thought that maybe I need to add a reference to `CellBlock, even though it's within the same solution, but when I click`Add Reference`, nothing is listed under project.

Comment: what line number causes the error?

Comment: @The lines that read `this.cellBlock1 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();` (see my edit).

Comment: try `this.cellBlock1 = new CellBlock();`

Comment: @Damith Isn't Visual Studio just going to overwrite that the next time I update the form? I know I could simply put the code from the designer.cs file into the main.cs file, but I'm trying to avoid doing that if at all possible (to rely on the automatically generated code as much as I can).

Comment: @pythonscript yes, you can change namespace to different one, don't change anything in designer.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename your namespace to new one other than `Sudoku` and then clean the solution and rebuild it.

remove current  `CellBlock`   controls and add them again .

Comment: Cleaning the solution fixed. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because your class `Sudoku` is the same as your namespace `Sudoku` so the compiler thinks there should be an inner class called `CellBlock` inside the class `Sudoku`. I don;t have a c# runtime and compiler handy so I cannot try and reproduce.

Try re-factoring either the namespace or class name so it has it's own identifier.

Comment: I re-factored the class name to `SudokuWindow`, which also re-factored the lines `this.cellBlock1 = new Sudoku.CellBlock();` to `this.cellBlock1 = new SudokuWindow.CellBlock();`, which still fails.

Comment: @pythonscript Right because `SudokuWindow` is the class, which does not have the `CellBlock` in it... you need to refactor so that the namespace and class are different, and so the generated code will say ... `new namespace.CellBlock()` -- and in future situations I would keep the package name unique to avoid these situations

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. The reason I'm hesitant to change those lines by hand (which I'll need to do because re-factoring the class *doesn't* updates those lines) and I don't want to change the designer.cs file by hand. When I re-factor the class, it changes the lines in question, which is still incorrect. If I re-factor the namespace, it doesn't change those lines (and therefore doesn't fix the problem) unless I manually change them.

Comment: I would just delete the namespace part from each `new namespace.CellBlock();` and if the code regenerates it should use the namespace instead this time ( as long as you refactored the class to be different then the namespace ) - theres probably a better way but since it's only a few lines I would just delete the namespace portion off each.

Comment: @pythonscript I posted a fix, replied back 3 times and not even so much as a thumbs up and then someone else posts the same thing and gets a thumbs up and accepted? I feel robbed! :p

Comment: To be fair, your fix didn't include cleaning the solution or removing the controls and re-adding them, the combination of which seemed to fix the problem. Simply re-factoring the class and/or namespace name didn't. +1 for tenacity, though.